# Calculating monthly precipitation mean for Brazilian municipalities

Tags: google-earth-engine

Need as final product a table with monthly precipitation mean for all brazlian municipalities in the year of 2006. I did this code, which I think it calculated this, but there's no date reference in feature properties, so I don't know of which month is the data.

Can someone help me?

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f9dc0699062630a105032cbff1c10413

Script:

```
var mun = ee.FeatureCollection("users/rodrigoccuri/BRMUE250GC_SIR");
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");


var monthlyPrecip = ee.FeatureCollection([]);

var monthly = chirps
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2006, 2006, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 12, 'month'))
        .sum();

var mun_month=monthly.reduceRegions(mun, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000);
monthlyPrecip=monthlyPrecip.merge(mun_month);

print(monthlyPrecip.first());


Export.table.toDrive(monthlyPrecip, 'precipbymun2', 'munprecip', 'MunPrecipitation');
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't mun_month already provide you with the answer when you export it?

```
// set start and end year
var start = 1;
var end = 12;



// make a list with years
var month = ee.List.sequence(start, end);

var monthlyPrecip = ee.FeatureCollection([]);

var monthly = chirps
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2006, 2006, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 12, 'month'))
        .sum();
print(monthly)

var mun_month=ee.FeatureCollection(monthly.reduceRegions(mun, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000));
print(mun_month.limit(10))
```

If you want to have it for each month in each year (time series) you'l have to put the collection filters and reduce region in a mapped function..

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I adapted the code to run for each month for each municipality. But idk why in the final result features are still without a property of month (I introduce in the code set function for this). Do you know what ould be worg?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I adapted the code to run for each month for each municipality. But idk why in the final result features are still without a property of month (I introduce in the code set function for this). Do you know what ould be wrong? Here's script:

```
// Filtering for year of reference:
var chirps06 = chirps.filterDate('2006-01-01', '2006-12-31');

// Set start and end year
var start = 1;
var end = 12;

// Make a list with years
var month = ee.List.sequence(start, end);

// Creating an empty Feature Collection:
var monthlyPrecip = ee.FeatureCollection([]);

// Creating a map function to run for every month:
var monthlyPrecip = function(mon) {
  var chirps_mon=chirps06.
  filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(mon, mon, 'month')).
  sum();
  var chirps_mean=chirps_mon.reduceRegions(mun, ee.Reducer.mean(),1000);
  return chirps_mean.set('month', mon);
}

// Mapping function to elements list (1:12):
var monthly = ee.FeatureCollection(month.map(monthlyPrecip)).flatten();

print(monthly.first());

//Export.table.toDrive(monthly, 'monthprecip06', 'Precipitation', 'monthprecip06');
```